# r devtools::test fails but all contexts are OK

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I am developing a R package using `devtools` and the associate `testthat` functionality. When I use `devtools::test()`, the console lists all the tested contexts (about 20). **All of which are executed correctly** with OK in 267 cases and 2 Warnings. However, the `== Results ===================` line summarizes as there being **one failed** test. Is this an arithmetic mistake by `testthat` or where did I go wrong?

[image: summary of my test() output]

I know this is not very specific, let alone reproducible. Help for narrowing it down is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this error was a script in the testthat folder which contained some failing code which was not wrapped in a `test_that("context", {...code...})`.